# Eclipse: Does only "Run As > Run On Server" call web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, web.xml

I have a Java script that currently, which I rightly click and select Run As > Java Application, launches a webpage with Jersey. It is not a servlet (though it calls a servlet through Jersey?... I think...)

However, I still have a web.xml file in my project folder.

Under what circumstances is web.xml called or not called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no matter what, if your web xml is there in your project, it will get referred when you run it on server
For more info on web xml read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml

Comment: what about if I run it just as a Java application?

Comment: Web xml is called deployment descriptor. Whenever something needs to be deployed it will be referred. run as java application just runs your compiled class.

Comment: I have edited answer with google app engine web inf link. Refer that also you can read on wiki